# What is the most suitable development framework for apache hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, spring-data, bigdata

I want to start development on some big data application based on apache hadoop. I want to know what is the best way to start development hadoop for novice. what are the available development framework and tools other than the Apache hadoop core ?

Further, Is there a good tutorial on Spring hadoop development on eclipse ?

Comment: @LuisAndrésGarcía Not actually. i want to know framework. Means Spring hadoop or pure hadoop or pangool or cascade or etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is just fine for hadoop development. In my expierance you do not need nothing special above of Java dev environment. Hadoop has very nice local mode when all deamons are running in one process and you can easily debug your MapReduce code. 
In practice it is usually enough to debug 99% of problems.
It is also possible to set up Hadoop dev environment with Eclipse on Windows. You will need  cygwing, but aside of it is easy.